# custom_post_type with has_archive doesn't change permalink

Tags: custom-post-types

I am not able to rewrite custom post type permalink.

```
 $labels = array(
            'name' => __('VmGallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN, THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'singular_name' => __('VmGallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'new_item' => __('New Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'all_items' => __('All Galleries', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'view_item' => __('View Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'search_items' => __('Search Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'not_found' => __('No galleries found', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No galleries found in the Trash', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => __('Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
        );
$supports = array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats', 'author', 'excerpt');

 $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'description' => 'Galleries specific information',
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 6,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
            'supports' => $supports,
            'taxonomies' => array('gallery_categories', 'post_tag'),
            'has_archive' => 'ggg'
            /*'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => $slug,
                'with_front' => false
            ),*/
        );

        register_post_type('vmgallery', $args);
```

I have php file: `archive-vmgallery.php` I think that it should be loaded when URL is `myurl.com/ggg`. But it shows 404 error page instead.
If I use post type instead of 'ggg': myurl.com/vmgallery, then `archive-vmgallery.php` is loaded. Why? I thought that 'has_archive' => 'ggg' allows to rewrite slug?

Comment: Did you try re-saving the permalink in settings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you change rewrite rules, you need to rebuild the rewrite rules in the database. You can do that `flush_rewrite_rules()` function, but don't use it in every page load, you only need to do it once. In general, a very good hook to do it is the `register_actionvation_hook()` of your plugin. You should rebuild the rewrite rules also when your plugin is deactivated in order to remove you custom rewrite rules:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, function () {
    cyb_register_vmgallery_post_type();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
} );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, function () {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
} );
add_action( 'init', 'cyb_register_vmgallery_post_type' );
function cyb_register_vmgallery_post_type() {
   $labels = array(
            'name' => __('VmGallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'singular_name' => __('VmGallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'new_item' => __('New Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'all_items' => __('All Galleries', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'view_item' => __('View Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'search_items' => __('Search Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'not_found' => __('No galleries found', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No galleries found in the Trash', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => __('Gallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
        );
    $supports = array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'post-formats', 'author', 'excerpt');

    $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'description' => 'Galleries specific information',
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 6,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
            'supports' => $supports,
            'taxonomies' => array('gallery_categories', 'post_tag'),
            'has_archive' => 'ggg'
            /*'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => $slug,
                'with_front' => false
            ),*/
        );

        register_post_type('vmgallery', $args);

}
```