# Single custom post type page redirecting to 404 page

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, single

I have declared post type as below:

```
 $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'agences'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'taxonomies' => array('brands', 'country'),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields')
    );

    register_post_type('destinations', $args);
```

Initially I was able to access single page of this post type using `single-agences.php` but now it is redirecting to 404.

I have checked other answers and found that its a common mistake but other answers were not able to resolve this.
Any help will be wonderful.

Comment: Because you are not using the default rewrite rules, you need to flush and rebuild them. See this: [custom\_post\_type with has\_archive doesn't change permalink](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219395/custom-post-type-with-has-archive-doesnt-change-permalink)

Comment: Your single file should be `single-destinations.php`, not with the rewrite rule. And your whole code should be inside a `init` hooked function.

Comment: I tried `single-destinations.php` before trying `single-agences.php` but that was not working. even if it does not use these file it should use `single.php` but its giving a 404 error.
and yes code is in `init` hooked funtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a plugin "Remove taxonomy base slug". It was conflicting with base slug of CPT "destinations". I had to use `add_rewrite_rule` to check for slug and manually redirect it to proper location

Answer (score 12):

Newly registered CPT shows 404 because, the `register_post_type()` doesn't flush the rewrite rules. So it's up to you, whether you want to do it manually or automatically.

## Manually:

Get to `/wp-admin/`, then Settings » Permalinks, and then just hit the <kbd>Save Changes</kbd> button to flush the rewrite rules.

## Automatically:

You can flush the rewrite rules using [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) function. But as `register_post_type()` is called in `init` hook, it will fire every time when the `init` hook will fire. The same thing the codex is saying also:

> *This function is useful when used with custom post types as it allows for automatic flushing of the WordPress rewrite rules (usually needs to be done manually for new custom post types). However, **this is an expensive operation** so it should only be used when absolutely necessary.*

That's why it's better to hook the thing to something that fire once, and that flush rules when necessary only. As [@cybmeta already showed that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/219395/22728) to you. But you can follow @bainternet's approach as well:

```
/**
 * To activate CPT Single page
 * @author  Bainternet
 * @link http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-post-type-getting-404-on-permalinks
 * ---
 */
$set = get_option( 'post_type_rules_flased_mycpt' );
if ( $set !== true ){
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );
    update_option( 'post_type_rules_flased_mycpt', true );
}
```

He is saving a value to `options` table only for your post type. And if the value is not there, he's flushing rewrite rules. If it's there, he's not doing it.

But please note, it's actually making a db call every time (if not cached). So, I'd prefer hooking the code [`after_setup_theme`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/) for theme, or [`register_activation_hook`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/) for plugin.

## Bonus

While debugging rewrite rules, plugin like these could be very helpful:

- [**Rewrite Rules Inspector** *by Automattic*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/)
- [**Rewrite Rule Testing** *by Matthew Boynes*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-testing/)
- [**Debug Bar Rewrite Rules** *by Frédéric GILLES*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-debug-bar-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: Its not newly registered CPT. Also I have tried flushing rewrite rule many time but it didn't worked.
When I use "plain" permalink format it works. But not with "Post name" permalink format.

Comment: Could you please confirm that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server and working for other standard URL of that WordPress installation? I'd love to recommend the [basic debug process](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info) too.

Comment: On sever I have many WordPress installation with multiple custom post types and all are working good.

Comment: Then it's impossible for us to detect. You can share your product using github, bitbucket, gitlab etc., so that someone can test whether it worked globally or, not. It's too localized to your dev. environment, that nobody can touch about, I'm afraid. :(

Comment: It was due to a plugin "Remove taxonomy base slug". It was conflicting with base slug of CPT "destinations". I had to use "add_rewrite_rule" to check for slug and manually redirect it to proper location.