# Making permalink for custom post type/custom taxonomy. Stuck with 404 in the single post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, 404-error, single

I have looked around noth in StackOverflow and WP.SE.

Like many before me, I just want this structure

```
mysite.com/custom-post-type/custom-taxonomy-term/post-name
```

Or, in other words,

```
mysite.com/publication/book/post-name (single post)
mysite.com/publication/book/          (all posts in the term 'book')
mysite.com/publication/               (all posts in this publication CPT)
```

I followed [this instruction by TheDeadMedic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5313/13291) for making custom post type with custom taxonomy permalink, and [another one by Matthew Boynes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/40591/13291) to fix the pagination issue.

All works well, except... everytime I open the single post, it returns the 404 page.

I have tried opening the Permalink page and setting [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219974/single-custom-post-type-page-redirecting-to-404-page) to no avail. I still can't open the single page.

The only fix that works is if I change the slug in my custom taxonomy to its original form.

So instead of `publication` (the rewrite slug for this tax, in accordance to my custom post type name), I would have the default `type` (the default slug for this tax). Which would defeat the purpose.

Here is my code.

Taxonomy.

```
    function cptui_register_my_taxes_type() {

/**
 * Taxonomy: Types.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'Types', 'mysite' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'Type', 'mysite' ),
    "menu_name" => __( 'Types', 'mysite' ),
    "all_items" => __( 'All Types', 'mysite' ),
    "edit_item" => __( 'Edit Types', 'mysite' ),
    "view_item" => __( 'View Type', 'mysite' ),
    "update_item" => __( 'Update Type Name', 'mysite' ),
    "add_new_item" => __( 'Add New Type', 'mysite' ),
    "new_item_name" => __( 'New Type Name', 'mysite' ),
    "parent_item" => __( 'Parent Type', 'mysite' ),
    "parent_item_colon" => __( 'Parent Type:', 'mysite' ),
    "search_items" => __( 'Search Types', 'mysite' ),
    "popular_items" => __( 'Popular Types', 'mysite' ),
    "separate_items_with_commas" => __( 'Separate Types with commas', 'mysite' ),
    "add_or_remove_items" => __( 'Add or remove Types', 'mysite' ),
    "choose_from_most_used" => __( 'Choose from the most used Types', 'mysite' ),
    "not_found" => __( 'No Types found', 'mysite' ),
    "no_terms" => __( 'No types', 'mysite' ),
    "items_list_navigation" => __( 'Types list navigation', 'mysite' ),
    "items_list" => __( 'Types list', 'mysite' ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( 'Types', 'mysite' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Types",
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'publication', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ),
    "show_admin_column" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
);
register_taxonomy( "tyoe", array( "publication" ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_type' );
```

Custom Post Type

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_publication() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Publication.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "menu_name" => __( 'Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "all_items" => __( 'All Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "add_new" => __( 'Add New', 'mysite' ),
        "add_new_item" => __( 'Add New Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "edit_item" => __( 'Edit Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "new_item" => __( 'New Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "view_item" => __( 'View Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "view_items" => __( 'View Publications', 'mysite' ),
        "search_items" => __( 'Search Publications', 'mysite' ),
        "not_found" => __( 'No publication found', 'mysite' ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( 'No trashed publications', 'mysite' ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( 'Parent Publication:', 'mysite' ),
        "featured_image" => __( 'Cover or illustration', 'mysite' ),
        "set_featured_image" => __( 'Set cover or illustration for this publication', 'mysite' ),
        "remove_featured_image" => __( 'Remove cover or illustration for this publication', 'mysite' ),
        "use_featured_image" => __( 'Use as cover or illustration for this publication', 'mysite' ),
        "archives" => __( 'Publication archives', 'mysite' ),
        "insert_into_item" => __( 'Insert into publication info', 'mysite' ),
        "uploaded_to_this_item" => __( 'Uploaded to publication info', 'mysite' ),
        "filter_items_list" => __( 'Filter publication', 'mysite' ),
        "items_list_navigation" => __( 'Publication list navigation', 'mysite' ),
        "items_list" => __( 'Publication list', 'mysite' ),
        "attributes" => __( 'Publication Attributes', 'mysite' ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( 'Parent Publication:', 'mysite' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'Publication', 'mysite' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "publication/%type%", "with_front" => false ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_position" => 6,
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-format-aside",
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "comments", "revisions" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "type" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "publication", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_publication' );
```

Setting up the permalink

```
function change_permalink_publication( $link, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type === 'publication' ) {
        if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'type' ) )
            $link = str_replace( '%type%', current( $terms )->slug, $link );
    }

    return $link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_permalink_publication', 10, 2 );


add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'change_permalink_publication_pagination' );
function change_permalink_publication_pagination( $wp_rewrite ) {
    unset($wp_rewrite->rules['publication/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$']);
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
        'publication/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?post_type=publication',
        'publication/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?post_type=publication&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ),
        'publication/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => $wp_rewrite->index . '?type=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 1 ) . '&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index( 2 ),
    ) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: if the questions you linked work, and your version doesn't, there would seem to be some difference, however most of the code you're using is not shown here, so it's difficult to say what that is.

Comment: @Milo edited, added the relevant CPT, custom taxonomy, and permalink setting.

Comment: I assume `"tyoe"` in `register_taxonomy` is a typo? The problem is `"hierarchical" => true` in your taxonomy. Those rewrite rules are capturing the request for single `publication` posts, it's looking for a `type` term matching your post name. You can fix it immediately if you just set `"hierarchical" => false`. If you really want a hierarchical taxonomy, it'll get a little more complicated.

Comment: @Milo: Ah yes, that's a typo (had to translate it from my language to make more sense). By the way, setting the `hierarchical` to `false` fixes it for now. Thanks! Would be nice if there's a way to allow hierarchical taxonomy though. :)